# How to group data on same value using _.each()

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

i have a set of JSON,

```
[{"gp_id":"1","gp_name":"ADMIN","gp_location":"Headquater"},{"gp_id":"2","gp_name":"OE.TT","gp_location":"Timah Tasoh"},{"gp_id":"3","gp_name":"OP.TT","gp_location":"Timah Tasoh"},{"gp_id":"4","gp_name":"USER.HQ","gp_location":"Headquater"}]
```

As you can see, the are some repetitive value in index "**gp_location**". How do i achieve a result like this using _.each (underscoreJs)

```
<select>
 <optgroup label="Headquater">
   <option>ADMIN</option>
   <option>USER.HQ</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Timah Tasoh">
   <option>OP.TT</option>
   <option>OE.TT</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

so far what i have achieve is this

```
    render: function() {
        this.$el.empty();
        var container = document.createDocumentFragment(),
            modelgroups = _.groupBy(this.collection.models, "gp_location");         
        _.each(modelgroups, function(group, n) {            
            var optgroup = document.createElement('optgroup');              
            optgroup.label = n;             
            _.each(group, function(base) {                  
                optgroup.appendChild(new BaseListItemView({model: base}).render().el)
            });             
            container.appendChild(optgroup);                
        }); 
        this.$el.append(container);
        return this;
    }
```

I'm developing a backboneJS application. As you can see **BaseListItemView** is a view of html element `option`. Am not sure on how to produce another view for `optgroup`

Update: here is code for `BaseListItemView`

```
 return Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: "option",

    initialize: function () {               
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.model.attributes.gp_name + ', ' + this.model.attributes.gp_location);
        this.$el.attr( "value" , this.model.attributes.gp_id )
        return this;
    }

});
```

Hope someone can help me.

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you show us the code of your `BaseListItemView` (or it's `render` method at least), please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`groupBy` function](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) like this:

```
var modelgroups = _.groupBy(this.collection.models, "gp_location");
```

so that you can iterate it with

```
_.each(modelgroups, function(group, name) {
    var $group = $("<optgroup>", {label:name});
    _.each(group, function(base) {             
        $group.append(new BaseListItemView({model: base}).render().el)
    });
    this.$el.append($group);
});
```

and you can remove the `gp_location` from your `<option>`-View.

Comment: No, you only need to adapt it. But you haven't shown your existing code to us, so I needed to come up with my own instead of helping you with yours. Please edit it into your question.

Comment: i have problem with `name` at the following line

     _.each(modelgroups, function(group, name) {

Comment: it return `undefine`. I have adopt your technic, see updated question above

Comment: Hm, the code works fine. Are you sure that `this.collection.models` is exactly the JSON you posted in the beginning? If the grouped-by property would not have been found it would make sense to get the items in a group named `"undefined"`.

Comment: yes. I'm sure because i still can get the other data.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer @bergi

not sure what has gone wrong, but here a slight changes to your answer

```
modelgroups = _.groupBy(this.collection.models, function(model){
    return model.get('gp_location')
    });
```

Comment: Seems the objects in the array weren't pure objects, but models - on which a plain property access doesn't work.

Comment: hi @Bergi, thanks for your thought. What do you mean not pure object. Is there anything i can fix

Comment: By "pure object" I mean a plain js object like the ones you parse from JSON - like the one you presented in your question. Yours seems to be a backbone model actually. This is however nothing bad, and when the above code does work you don't need to fix anything.